# Windows batch script for searching files based on file name,checks if the files are older than N days, if true, it deletes those files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am a newbie to windows batch scripting. I have researched through the web and the site and tried out the solutions but none seem to give me the desired results.

This is what I want to achieve:

---

1. Search for files in a folder using a specific filename
2. show found files
3. Check the found files if they are older than 1 day
4. If true,delete those files
5. Else return message(Found files not older than 1 day)

From my research I was able to write a batch code that searches for file using a string, but unable to do step 2,3,4 and 5.

Kindly assist.

Here is my batch code:

---

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "MySearchString=Scheduled_error"
for /r %%a in (*) do for /f "delims=" %%i in ('echo("%%~na" ^| findstr /i "%MySearchString%"') do echo del "%%~fa"
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelS,that was really helpful. Marichyasana,thanks for your contribution .

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a perfect task for `FORFILES`!

`forfiles /p c:\SomePath\ /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @path"` will show you all files older than one day. You can modify the filter replacing `*.*` with the file name you are looking for.

To delete these files simply replace `echo @path` with `del /y @path` and add the `/d -1` parameter:

```
forfiles /p c:\SomePath /s /m *.* /d -1 /c "cmd /c del /y @path"
```

The age of the files to delete is specified with the `/d -1` switch where `-1` means 1 day and older.

Comment: `forfiles` (at least under Windows 7) does *not* match files with no extension if using mask `*.*` (or even `*.`); therefore mask `*` (default) should be used for catching all items...